# Multiple Jquery Functions

Tags: jquery

Total noob to jquery, i want to add another function on the cotsImg.hover event, to change a second image - just like it changes one below. something like

```
<script  type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cotsImg").hover(
       function() {$('#golfImg').attr("src","/images/golfimagebw.png");}, 
       function() {$('#golfImg').attr("src","/images/golfimage.png");
       function() {$('#golfImg2').attr("src","/images/golfimage2bw.png");}, 
       function() {$('#golfImg2').attr("src","/images/golfimage2.png");

});
});
</script>
```

Can anyone help? Its been a long day of trying this!

Comment: Could you show us the HTML?

Comment: You want to replace with new image on each hover? Explain better please

Comment: You should have 2 functions the first one for mouseenter the second one for mouseleave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need  to pass two functions.

From [Jquery Docs of Hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

> The .hover() method, when passed a single function, will execute that handler for both mouseenter and mouseleave events.

So, your one function executing for both the  events . You need to remove it after hover done

```
$("#selectorId").hover(
function() {
   //Do something to element here
},

 function() {
    //make your element normal here
   }

);
```

Or classic style.

```
 $("#cotsImg")
        .mouseover(function() { 

            $(this).attr("src", "/images/golfimagebw.png");
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
             $(this).attr("src", "/images/golfimage.png");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script  type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cotsImg").hover(function(){
       $('#golfImg').attr("src","/images/golfimagebw.png"); 
       $('#golfImg').attr("src","/images/golfimage.png");
       $('#golfImg2').attr("src","/images/golfimage2bw.png"); 
       $('#golfImg2').attr("src","/images/golfimage2.png");

});
});
</script>
```

just like that add what you want :)

Comment: You might want to put the second and last selector - attribute functions in the second hover callback. I think that's what he wants

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then you don't need more functions, just execute those lines of code excluding the functions.